# I've got an error for using "Super(props)" in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

when I was making an app following this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Fkx87SMoJc. I got an error;

[image]

I also saw some line on super(props); in VS code;

[image]

Here is my code please fix the problem by correcting my code because I'm still a beginner.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Splash from './components/splash';
import Home from './components/index';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { CurrentScreen: 'Splash' };
    console.log('Moving to next screen...');
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('Done!');
      this.setState({ CurrentScreen: 'Home' });
    }, 3000)
  }
  render() {
    const { CurrentScreen } = this.state
    let mainScreen = CurrentScreen === 'Splash' ? <Splash /> : <Home />
    return mainScreen
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => Splash)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: avoid putting errors as images. i am sure the error appears in the console as well. put that instead of pictures.

Comment: the error has nothing to do with Super. your code does not have an export line. may be export your component and see if the error goes away? export default Main;

Comment: are you sure about: AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => Splash)
??? so what does Main() do? isn't it AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => Main)???

Comment: Please, I don't know anything I was just following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Fkx87SMoJc,  but then I got an error.